# Set Div position to Mouse position with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to position my Div wherever the user clicks on my Image.

**test** is my Div, and **myimg** is my image.

Here is my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myimg").click(function(e){
                             $("#test").show(2000);
                             $("#test").offset({left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY});

                             })
})
</script>
```

However that does not work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the Div wont show up, if I include the offset line, if I dont, it shows, but not at the right position.

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>xSky Software - Most likely the only software on Clickbank that exists.</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='video/jwplayer.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myimg").click(function(e){
                             $("#test").show(2000);
                             $("#test").offset({left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY});

                             })
})
</script>


</head>
<body>
    <!--Header and Logo-->
    <div id="header">
            <div id='mainvid'>This text will be replaced</div> 
            <script type='text/javascript'>
              jwplayer('mainvid').setup({
                'flashplayer': 'video/player.swf',
                'file': 'video/Untitled1.mp4',
                'controlbar': 'none',
                'frontcolor': 'FFFFFF',
                'lightcolor': 'FFFFFF',
                'screencolor': 'FFFFFF',
                'autostart': 'true',
                'width': '709',
                'height': '422'
              });
            </script>            
            </div>   
    </div>


    <div id="test" style="width:100px; position:absolute; display:none; height:100px; border:#093 solid 2px; background:#0C6;">
    Teeest
    </div>

    <!--Content-->
    <div id="content">            
        <center><img src="Images/downloadbutton.png" id="myimg" /></center>   
        <br />
        <div class="text">
        OH YEAH!
        </div> 
    </div>



    <!--Footer-->
    <div id="footer">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Details on what exactly "does not work," please.

Comment: How about an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: @Matt- Sorry, was/am in a hurry

Comment: My bad - the Image was overlapping the div.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to work fine.  I have set up a JSFiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/JPvya/

Click on the image and the test div moves.  The only change is using the $ short notation for JQuery instead of typing "JQuery" which, by the way is probably case sensetive and causing the problem!

Comment: Then as you suggest - the problem is elsewhere :-)

Comment: Accepted this, as this helped me identify what was the actual cause.

Answer (score 19):

I think you probably want

```
$("#test").css({position:"absolute", left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY});
```

instead of

```
$("#test").offset({left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY});
```

Comment: This needs more upvotes, this is the better solution. If you offset more than once, it keeps moving again and again and again until the object is unreachable.

Answer (score 3):

This works well enough for me, so your problem is likely elsewhere.

#### HTML

```
<img id="myimg" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
<span id="test">This is a test</span>
```

#### CSS

```
#test {
    display: none;
    color: white;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $("#myimg").click(function(e) {
        var o = {
            left: e.pageX,
            top: e.pageY
        };
        $("#test").show(2000).offset(o);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/haFMn/