# Creating a popup window on the click's position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a canvas element on my site on which the user can select several things. For more choice what to do with the selected thing I want to create a small popup with a few options. Unfortunately I am not able to put the popup on the same position the click was.

My first approach is to do the popup with a div. 
I have a Div:

```
    <div id = "popup" style="visibility: hidden">
    text
    </div>
```

To change the div's status and position I use this code:

```
    $(popupDiv).offset({ top: mousePos.y, left:  mousePos.x});
```

Unfortunately the position the div pops up is not similar to where it should be.

Any Ideas why?

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088887/set-div-position-to-mouse-position-with-jquery

Comment: @Precastic - similar, but unless you happen to notice the inline style of `position: absolute` in the asker's markup, doubt he would have found the answer.  it was apparently a different issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `#popup` div is `position: absolute`, not `relative`.  Otherwise, its offset will be relative to where the block element would have been drawn.

Here is a basic fiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWyYc/)

**edit:** Should have mentioned - if you don't specify `absolute` yourself, when using the `.offset()` method, it will automatically use `relative`.