# How to make an element appear on the cursor coordinates (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, html, coordinates

I made the following jQuery code:

```
$(".button").live("click", function(){  // When you click on .button...
    $(this).before(" <div class='add'> +1 </div> ");  // ...a new div appears.
});
```

The new "+1" div is currently styled to appear in a predetermined position.

Can you help me pass the cursor coordinates to the div position, in order to make the div appear where the user clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/JPvya/1109/

Note: i would use allways the same div to have more clear the DOM. But, if you need a DIV for each click, change the code in order to create a new div each click.
HTML

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body id="BodyID">
        <div id='test'>Test div is testing</div>
        <hr></hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#test {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

jquery script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#BodyID").click(function(e){
         $("#test").show(2000);
         $("#test").offset({left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY});

         })
})
```

Reference: [Set Div position to Mouse position with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088887/set-div-position-to-mouse-position-with-jquery)